# Meaning of the (idiomatic?) expression "seghe mentali"

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, idioms, phrase-request

Oggi ho visto un'immagine di un libro di un certo Giacobbe intitolato "come smettere di farsi le seghe mentali e godersi la vita".

Qualcuno mi sa spiegare il significato delle parole "seghe mentali"?

Comment: Può essere utile notare che "sega" ha il significato (volgare) di "masturbazione maschile", a cause della somiglianza tra il movimento avanti e indietro ripetitivo della sega (l'utensile) e...uhm... altri movimenti.

Answer (score 8):

La *sega mentale* o *pippa mentale* significa portare avanti un ragionamento contorto, farraginoso e oltremodo inutile che complica una situazione che sarebbe molto più semplice; una sorta di “masturbazione” delle meningi.

Treccani per [pippa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pippa2_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) ne riporta le principali caratteristiche:

> 3. [occupazione futile, insulsa o noiosa: che p.!] ≈ (pop.) palla, (pop.) pizza, (volg.) rottura (di coglioni), seccatura.

In questo simpatico articolo di un blog  [*La sostenibile inutilità delle cose*](https://www.google.com/amp/s/lecoseinutili.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/la-sega-mentale/amp/) ne viene data una spiegazione più argomentata:

> Le seghe mentali sono quasi sempre malefiche (occhio malocchio
>   prezzemolo e finocchio non c’entra nulla…) e si formano con un “ma se
>   io…”, “ e se io…”..”, “eh si, però pure io…”, “se solo io…”, che poi
>   diventano “Ma se lui..allora io…” , “e se lui….”, “eh si però pure
>   lui….”, “se solo lui….” Lo stadio successivo è il passaggio diretto
>   all’alienazione dalla realtà.

Answer (score 0):

Il libro dice:

Dicesi «sega mentale» il pensare a cose che non hanno attinenza con la realtà

Comment: Scusa, puoi specificare quale libro afferma ciò?